# Want to remove duplicate key value using regex

Tags: regex

I have logs like in this format and wanted a unique key value by using regex.

```
{
url_path:"/v1/test/user",
transaction_id:"ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM",
},

{
url_path:"/v1/test/user",
transaction_id:"ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM",
},

{
url_path:"/v1/test/user",
transaction_id:"DFJD-DFDF-DDFFF",
}
```

I'm trying in this way but not working -

`(?<transaction_id>[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-0]+-[A-Z0-9]+)`

Getting output -

```
ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM
ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM
DFJD-DFDF-DDFFF
```

Excepted output in unique key value. Like this -

```
ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM
DFJD-DFDF-DDFFF
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Which OS? As you're getting the values, all that is left is to write them to a file, sort and filter unique values.

Comment: This requirement is for the Sumo Logic  log management tool/
Their website - https://www.sumologic.com/